# Select filter dhtmlx show html encoded special chars

Tags: dhtmlx

I have a Select filter on a dhtmlx grid table,

on this filter, we have values that containst "&", "<", and ">".

On the table, the values of these fields, are good, but on the select filter, the values of these fields are on html encoded "&" -> &, "<" -> < and ">" -> >

How we can show the correct character on Select Filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try to use the "edtxt" column type instead of "ed".
Here is the example:
http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/a2a0b1a80